# Selecting expressions from a sequence that are not subexpressions of earlier elements

Tags: programming, performance-tuning, evaluation, pattern-matching, expression-manipulation

I have a `While` loop that generates and prints an expression on each iteration (there can be thousands of iterations). *UPDATE:* Some expressions are generated in unevaluated form (e.g. `1 + 1`) and printed in this form. This behavior should be kept in the modification explained below.

I want to modify it to print only *new* expressions — that do not appear as  sub-expressions of any expression that has been generated at an earlier step. We assume that any expression is a sub-expression of itself, so no expression should be printed twice. Generated expressions may contain patterns, and they should be handled verbatim (each symbol represents only itself). For example:

```
(* Iteration 1 *)
f[_] (* PRINTED *)

(* Iteration 2 *)
f (* Skipped *)

(* Iteration 3 *)
_ (* Skipped *)

(* Iteration 4 *)
Blank (* Skipped *)

(* Iteration 5 *)
f[0] (* PRINTED *)

(* Iteration 6 *)
f[_] (* Skipped *)

(* Iteration 7 *)
g[f[0]] (* PRINTED *)
```

What is the most efficient way to maintain a set of expressions that have been already printed and validate newly generated expressions against this set?

Comment: By `unevaluated form` you mean `Unevaluated`? Because part "(e.g `1+1`)" suggest it is rather `Defer`.

Comment: `Print[Unevaluated[1+1]]` prints `1+1` but if we do for example `expr={Unevaluated[1+1]}`, `Print[First@expr]` prints as `Unevaluated[1+1]`. I think this is the problem, but I haven't got a solution.

Comment: All generated expressions are wrapped in `HoldForm`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this and let me know if there are cases it misses:

```
exprs = {f[_], f, _, Blank, f[0], f[_], g[f[0]]};
taken = {};
Do[
 If[! MemberQ[taken, Verbatim[i]], Print[i]];
 taken = Union[{Head[i]}, Level[i, {0, Infinity}], taken];
 , {i, exprs}]

(* Out:
f[_]
f[0]
g[f[0]] *)
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that some expressions are in unevaluated form. I updated my question.